# C++ Exception Handling Questions

Tags: c++, winapi

1) For convenience I have my entire program in a try block. This way I can throw an exception at any point in my code and know that it will be handled the same way. As the program becomes larger will this technique cause a hit in performance?

2) If objects are de-allocated when out of scope, why would throwing a temporary object be valid? e.g.:

```
class Error : public std::exception  
{
  private:
    char *m;
  private:
    Error(char *l) : m(l) {}
    virtual char *what()
    {
      return m;
    }
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw Error("test");
  }
  catch(std::exception &e)
  {
    puts(e.what());
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the throw statement, why wouldn't the temporary object become invalid since it's been declared only in the try scope?

3) With Windows operating systems of a language other than English, would the `what()` member of the STL exception class still return a `char*` string? Or could it return a `wchar_t*` string?

Comment: You really should not have your whole program in a try block. If you get any error, your whole program ends rather than allowing you to elegantly handle it and continue. This kinda defeats the purpose of exceptions.

Comment: I disagree, if you log meaningful information from the exception at this level then it is perfectly valid. It gives you better information than if std::terminate was called, which is what happens if the exception isn't caught.

Comment: @JoshD within certain areas of my code I could have more try-catch blocks, with which I could elegantly handle exceptions. The first try-catch block would be to handle fatal errors where the program could not continue further.

Comment: @radman: I wasn't saying that no catching should be done. I was saying that having one huge try block around the whole program is not as useful as having finer grain try and catch blocks. I agree that catching an exception is better than letting the program crash.

Comment: How could the return type of the function change at runtime?

Comment: Note that the `what` function needs to be `const` to be an override. Also its result type should be `char const*`.

Answer (score 10):

Technically you don't throw the actual object, you throw a copy of it. That's why you can get away with throwing a temporary. Catching a reference also gets a reference to the copy.

This can bite you if you rethrow an exception from within a catch block, you can fall victim to the slicing problem. That's why you don't do:

```
catch (std::exception & e)
{
    throw e;  // bad, always throws std::exception rather than what was caught
}
```

But rather

```
catch (std::exception & e)
{
    throw;  // good, rethrows the exact copy that you caught without making another copy
}
```

P.S. There's no rule saying you couldn't return a UTF-8 string from `what`. It would be up to you to convert it to UTF-16 for Windows I/O. The standard exception classes were never explicitly designed or extended for Unicode, nor are any non-standard extensions added just for Windows.

Comment: actually... at least on MSVC (2005), rethrowing with e.g. `throw e;` works as long as you catched by reference...

Comment: @smerlin: for Mark's first example, "working" means slicing the exception. If it doesn't do that, it's a non-compliant C++ implementation.

Comment: @Steve: did another test, and the catch clauses surrounding the rethrow, only catched the exception as a std::exception, but the debugger still showed all information of the original exception. So it seems the compiler is standard compliant, at least in release mode, it slices the exception completely.

Answer (score 4):

1)
Having the whole program in a try block will not incur any performance hit, apart from that incurred by having exceptions enabled at all

2)
It is OK because you are throwing by value. Throwing by value means that whatever you throw is copied when thrown. So throwing any temporary is perfectly valid because a copy is made.

3)
The std::exception class, as far as I can determine, can only ever throw a `char*`. However you could always subclass it and implement support for wchar if you wanted.

It is worth noting that you shouldn't *just* have a try catch around `main()` if that is what you were intending.